# If eigenvector matrix $P$ diagonalizes both $A$ and $B$, prove $A$ and $B$ commute under matrix multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble proving the following statement:

Suppose that an eigenvector matrix $P$ diagonalizes both of the matrices $A$ and $B$. Prove that $A$ and $B$ commute under matrix multiplication.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$P^{-1}AP=D_A$$
$$P^{-1}BP=D_B$$
$$AB=PD_AP^{-1}PD_BP^{-1}=PD_AD_BP^{-1}=PD_BD_AP^{-1}=PD_BP^{-1}PD_AP^{-1}=BA$$